# How can I dynamically change the UIID for the commands that go in the toolbar?

Tags: codenameone

Currently I am adding the effects to an Image and then I use that as the pressedIcon Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Button btn = toolbar.findCommandComponent(cmd);
```

This will allow you to manipulate the button as you choose (e.g. `setUIID` etc.).